# gitlab issues remove uploaded designs

Tags: git, gitlab, github-issues

I uploaded desgins for the issues, but can not find the any delete option.
How can i delete it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume that's GitHub Enterprise? Does https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/deleting-an-issue work?

Comment: And if you want to change the images, maybe use the edit button on the top right?